# Jquery Mobile "Stack" Navigation issue

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, navigation

I'm having trouble with pages navigation using jQuery Mobile + Phonegap on Android.
I'm trying to replicate the Android stack navigation.

Here's the situation:

User is not logged and is on Main Page

1. Clicks on "**Action A**", that needs to be logged.
2. Show **Login** page.
3. Show "**Action A**" page.

The problem is:
When the user presses the back button, it should return to Main page and not the Login page.

But the "stack" in history is like this:

**Main | Login | Action A**

I tried to do:

```
// return from Login page to Main:
history.back(); // $.mobile.back(); works the same way in this case.

// then go to Action A page:
$.mobile.changePage( pageA );
```

But the "changepage" is performed after the "back" command, so it goes to the Action A page and then back to Login page.

On Android it's a very simple task. :(

Comment: Have a look at the changehash option: http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't call "back" and navigate to the next page.

In the "**onBackPressed**" event handler check the JQM stack and use the history.go( -2 ). Something like this:

```
var index = $.mobile.navigate.history.activeIndex - 1;
if ( index >= 0 ) {
    var backStep = -1; // back one by default
    var hash;
    while ( index > 0 ) {
        hash = $.mobile.navigate.history.stack[ index ].hash;

        if ( hash == "#pageLogin" ) {
            backStep--;
        }

        index--;
    }

    window.history.go( backStep );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.history.go(-2) //Go two pages back
```

or the same method twice

```
history.back(); //Go one page back
history.back(); //Go another one page back
```